# Unable to install Lubuntu 20.4

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, lubuntu

I'm trying to install Lubuntu on a Dell laptop. I'm trying dual boot, already have installed windows 10 in UEFI mode. I've allocated 16gigs of ext4 for root, 4 gigs for swap and 500mb for /boot/efi.
Lubuntu installer asks to set flag to esp for efi partition but esp flag isn't present so after searching online I've seen people using 'boot' flag for EFI partition. Installer proceeds to end but it fails after displaying an error boost python error in job bootloader.

[image: the error]

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has the same problem, I'm leaving this answer for reference.
So I was trying to create a second UEFI partition on hdd. First one being used by windows. You just need to point Ubuntu installer to existing UEFI partition using the flag boot.